# Inconsistent data when reading from ZK immediately after a write (using rest calls)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Does ZK need some sort of delay after a successful write, before the data can be read back, in case of a standalone instance (no peers)?

I have a test in which I create 1000 records using 1000 rest calls to a service, and then try to read them all back together. It works most of the time, but I seem to intermittently run into an issue where I only seem to get back a partial result (say 995 records).

My understanding was that a sync() was only required for consistency in case of multiple peers; is this not the case? Is there some specific delay that goes in beyond that, and if so, is there an upper limit to it?

P.S.: Since I'm using rest calls, perhaps the ZK clients are different instances; is this the problem? Would a sync (or a fixed sleep interval) fix it if so?